# Prove that if $∑_{n=0}^∞a_n$ converges and $∑_{n=0}^∞b_n$ converges absolutely, the $∑_{n=0}^∞a_n b_n$ converges absolutely.

Tags: calculus

Prove that if $∑_{n=0}^∞a_n$  converges and $∑_{n=0}^∞b_n$  converges absolutely, the $∑_{n=0}^∞a_n  b_n$ converges absolutely.

This is what I know

$∑_{n=0}^∞a_n$  converges, implies $lim_{n->\infty} a_n =0$
$∑_{n=0}^∞b_n$  converges absolutely,implies $∑_{n=0}^∞b_n$  converges, thus $lim_{n->\infty} b_n =0$.

I want to show that$∑_{n=0}^∞|a_n  b_n|$ converges. Since $|a_nb_n|\geq 0$, $∑_{n=0}^∞|a_n  b_n|$ is monotonic increasing. I only need to prove that $∑_{n=0}^∞|a_n  b_n|$ is bounded above, then I'm done. However, I don't know how to used what I know to complete the last piece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, then the sequence $(a_n)$ goes to zero, and thus $|a_n|$ is bounded above by some $A$. Then:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_nb_n|\le A\sum_{n=0}^\infty|b_n|<\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** in particular, $a_n\operatorname*{\to}_{n\to\infty} 0$, so $|a_n b_n|=o(|b_n|)$. Now, use the fact that $\sum b_n$ converges absolutely, and the comparison theorem.